# VueJS validation triggers incorrectly

Tags: vue.js

In my vueJS application I have a model component with a form. In that form I have a field for end date and there is a check box to select if the project does not have an end date..

```html
<div>
  <div class="w-1/2 ml-2">
      <p class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">End date</p>
      <div class="h-12">
          <cs-date-picker
              id="endDate"
              v-model="project.end_date"
              :default-selection="true"
              :name="`${identifier}-end_at`">
          </cs-date-picker>
          <validator
              :identifier="`${identifier}-validate-project`"
              :rules="validations.endDate"
              :name="`${identifier}-end_at`"
          />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="w-full">
      <label class="inline-flex items-center focus:outline-none checkbox--container mt-5">
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="opt_in"
              ref="checkBox"
              :checked="project.is_valid_forever"
          >
          <span class="checkbox--checkmark flex items-center justify-center ">
              <svg class="icon text-certstyle-orange feather feather-check"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                  <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12"></polyline>
              </svg>
          </span>
          <span style="bottom: 4px;" class="text-certstyle-text font-normal text-sm relative">This project has no start & end date.</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And following is my validation rule for end date.

```js
endDate: {
  required: {
      message: 'Project Start date is required.'
  },
  dateIsNowOrLater: {
      message: 'Date must be a future date.'
  },
},
```

Now, my problem is, even when an user checks "This project has no start & end date", it trigger the end date validation... how can I avoid this if the user check the check box...

Comment: well it's expected, if a field is required. Try to see if there is a required_if / required_unless rule, i guess it's vee-validate but not all versions have the same rules. If there is no rule to do that, you will need to define one

Comment: What validation library are you using? Vue has no build-in validation. Also what version - both validation library nad Vue

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple way to tackle this, I'm not sure what validation package you use but a couple of them have the `requiredIf` rule which you can use.

If you package does not have this rule you can do something like (pseudo code):

```js
computed: {
  dynamicValidationRule() {
    let required = undefined
    if(!this.project.is_valid_forever) {
      required = {
        message: 'Project Start date is required.'
      }
    }

    return {
      required,
      dateIsNowOrLater: {
        message: 'Date must be a future date.'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<validator
  :identifier="`${identifier}-validate-project`"
  :rules="dynamicValidationRule"
  :name="`${identifier}-end_at`"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but even with this still am getting the validation error